# Typescript narrow type conditionally based on Generic type union (string)

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types, narrowing

I have a couple of types defining roles :

```js
type UserIsAdmin = // some model
type UserIsVendor = // some model
type UserIsConsumer = // some model

type UserRole = 'admin' | 'vendor' | 'consumer'

type SessionRoles = {
  userIsAdmin: UserIsAdmin | null
  userIsVendor: UserIsVendor | null
  userIsConsumer: UserIsConsumer | null
}
```

And I'm trying to extract a type which takes a `UserRole` in generic param; and returns `SessionRoles` filtered by it (there is no need to make this automatically with a template string or anything like this; just conditional stuff).

What I tried :

```js
type SessionCheckedRoles<Role extends UserRole> = {
  userIsAdmin: Role extends 'admin' ? UserIsAdmin : null
  userIsVendor: Role extends 'vendor' ? UserIsVendor : null
  userIsConsumer: Role extends 'consumer' ? UserIsConsumer : null
}
```

It works when calling with a single `UserRole` :

```js
type AdminSessionRoles = SessionCheckedRoles<'admin'>
// Resolved to
{
  userIsAdmin: UserIsAdmin
  userIsVendor: null
  userIsConsumer: null
}
```

But it doesn't when I pass a union type :

```js
type VendorConsumerSessionRoles = SessionCheckedRoles<'vendor' | 'consumer'>
// Resolved to
{
  userIsAdmin: null
  userIsVendor: UserIsVendor | null
  userIsConsumer: UserIsConsumer | null
}
```

---

I'd like a type that would behave like this :

```js
type VendorConsumerSessionRoles = SessionCheckedRoles<'vendor' | 'consumer'>
// Resolved to
{
  userIsAdmin: null
  userIsVendor: UserIsVendor
  userIsConsumer: UserIsConsumer
}
```

Comment: 'a' | 'b' extends 'a' is not true, while the opposite is.

Comment: In case nullptr's comment isn't obvious enough, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mA86ZN) is what they're suggesting.  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer if @nullptr doesn't want to; otherwise what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks both of you. Inverting the "extends" conditional is the solution <3
I can accept anyone puttin this in answer